# Server error when attempting to use the inquestion:<id> and inquestion:this search operators

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, 500-server-error

When I try to use  `inquestion:389834` or `inquestion:this`, I get a 500 HTTP status code:

[image: screenshot of the error screen]

I would really like to use this function.

Comment: A similar problem: [Server error when searching in my saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389911/196432)

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the same issue is happening with the `inquestion:x` search term on all posts on all sites. Repeated testing of this with different questions yields the same message.

Comment: Do I wait to mark this as the answer or wait till an admin acknowledge's it?  Not used to bug question's been 4 hours and this is the only answer.

Comment: @BigJoe - I think you should wait because this is just an answer that explains the bug rather than one that announces a fix of it.

Comment: @BigJoe would make more sense to accept the other answer, actually. :)

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Seems to be fixed now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A389834) I've tested it with different questions and different sites and none of them error now.