# Server error when searching in my saves

Tags: bug, search, 500-server-error, saves

Searching in my [“saves”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/saves) (with the [`in:saves`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves) operator) does not currently work and
displays the [error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error)

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

This happens on all sites, at least since yesterday.

It might be related to the recently reported [Server error when attempting to use the inquestion:<id> and inquestion:this search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389879/196432) .

Comment: Did you flag the question for a moderator so they can put status-review? I was advised so now I'm just waiting

Comment: Duplicate? Regression? [I can't search for my Saves in stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390435/i-cant-search-for-my-saves-in-stackexchange-com)

Comment: @tripleee: It seems  that `in:saves` works (now) on each individual site, but not on https://stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Just like [with `inquestion:<id>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389980/1200429), this seems to now be fixed. I've tested it on various different sites and it now works on all of them.

Comment: it would still be nice to get a staff report on this- what caused it, and how it got fixed.

Comment: @starball I would like that too, but since neither question has been marked [status-completed], I posted an answer to let everyone know it had been fixed.

Comment: @TheThonnu IT could break again. I saw you posted on my question also. I asked in chat and they said we should wait till staff says something.